# Seekbar OnProgressChanged doesn't get fired when moving manually

Tags: android-seekbar

I have an app that is supposed to do some stuff when the seekbar is moved (manually). However, onProgressChanged never gets executed, even though I made sure that the progress value does change when moving the bar.

onStartTrackingTouch and onStopTrackingTouch both get fired without any problems.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
...



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, `onProgressChanged()` not fired, but `onStartTrackingTouch()` and `onStopTrackingTouch()` no such problem.

In my case, user not able to drag seekbar after re-enter the activity page, it happen randomly.

It's because of `mediaControl.seek()` code inside `onProgressChanged()` stuck. The way I fixed it is to ensure mediaControl object assigned is the latest one with valid duration (i.e. `mediaControl.getDuration()`'s `onSucces()` != 0L).

So if you have similar problem, please first check your object inside `onProgressChanged()`, it probably something wrong with that object.