# onProgressChanged() not called after moving progress button manually

Tags: android, video, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have the following code to add a SeekBar to a video:

```
final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

final MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this) {
    ...
    // Commented out irrelevant code.
}

mediaController.show();
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            final int topContainerId1 = getResources().getIdentifier("mediacontroller_progress",
                    "id", "android");
            final SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) mediaController.findViewById(topContainerId1);

            seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                int overall_progress = 0;

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    ...
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    videoView.seekTo((int) (videoView.getDuration() * (seekBar.getProgress() / 1000.0)));
                }
           });
       }
});
```

Everything works fine, and the seeker indicator is aligned with the video while it is playing. When I move the seek button manually, the video goes to the right place.

**My Problem**: If I pause the video and then start playing again, the seekbar progress indicator no longer moves even though the video plays again. I checked to see if *onProgressChanges()* was called in this situation, but it is never even called! Does anyone know a fix for this? It appears that this person also had the problem, but nobody answered their post: [Seekbar OnProgressChanged doesn't get fired when moving manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29200087/seekbar-onprogresschanged-doesnt-get-fired-when-moving-manually)